# Azure ML workbench failed installing on Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: windows, azure-machine-learning-service

Error installing component: azure_cli_ml_cliextension.windows "The action failed catastrophically with

Microsoft.MachineLearning.Installer.Engine.Actions.RegisteredActions.AzureCliException: Unable to get list of currently installed Azure CLI extensions

at

Microsoft.MachineLearning.Installer.Engine.Actions.RegisteredActions.InstallAzureCliExtensionAction.d__23.MoveNext() in C:\swarm\workspace\Installer-1.2\Installer.Engine\Actions\RegisteredActions\InstallAzureCliExtensionAction.cs:line 97

from there everything is stops....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workbench is a preview product and issues may occur. Please try and get a newer exe and try again. It also seems like you have azure powershell issues here which I would have expected to be taken care of by the installer, but perhaps you can try and install azure powershell first.

Comment: Thanks Dan I will try it out but this certainly works on the MAC.

Comment: before trying to reinstall, please make sure you completely remove your original install. I have for the most part not had issues, but an exe or two have gotten published that had issues.

Comment: See the scripts here for more details on how to remove it completely - https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearning-Scripts/tree/master/cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Not your issue I think but i'll pop it here in case others have problems. For me the installer failed to do anything though it claimed to be installed. Turns out it had just dropped the files and the installer exe needed to be run manually. The installer exe was dropped here

> C:\Users{User}\AppData\Local\AmlInstaller\Installer.Windows.exe

Non-obvious to tired developers trying to do a bit extra at the end of a busy day